# Startup script on Ubuntu 12.04 not getting executed. Dependencies / load order. 

Tags: ubuntu, boot, shell-script

I want to create a simple startup script on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
myscript.sh

#!/bin/sh
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
cd ~/app/current
god -c config/resque.god
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
echo "SCRIPT RUN"
```

I have it at /etc/init.d/myscript.sh

When I do

```
sudo chkconfig --level 2345 myscript.sh
```

I get
    myscript.sh  2345

When I do

```
 sudo chkconfig --add myscript.sh
```

I get

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01myscript.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'myscript.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and overrides
....
myscript.sh               0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

**** EDIT::

I checked the boot.log and it turns out that the script is run, but the problem is that god is not loaded yet when the script is executed. Apparently I want to load this script as the very last thing at startup (or somehow check if god is loaded and then start the script).

Answer (score 2):

You will also, probably, have problems with the `cd ~/app/current` line. `~` means the current user's home directory. I don't know what user scripts in `init.d` are run as, root I would imagine, but I guess you are referring to your own `$HOME` not root's. In that case, you should use absolute paths.

If I understand the `chkconfig` line correctly, you are telling the system to run your scripts at init levels 2 through 5. Since it is a high level script that depends on other modules being loaded etc, you should only run it a later runlevels. Have a look at [this page](http://www.skullbox.net/init.php) for more info on runlevels.

Based on the `chkconfig` man page, it looks like what you want is:

```
sudo chkconfig myscript.sh 35
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is because you are missing LSB tags. To a purist, your init.d script is horrible because it contains no comments about what it is trying to achieve, does not have start/stop functions, and generally does not behave like an init.d script. However for your purposes that doesn't matter too much unless you are working on a shared system. I would suggest putting comments in every single script you ever write about the purpose, when it was written and by who - it is just good practice.

http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Have a look at the man page (http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) specifically this section:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Saves and restores system entropy pool for \
#              higher quality random number generation.
```

Or LSB style stanzas:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: foo
# Required-Start: bar
# Defalt-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Foo init script
### END INIT INFO
```

Which are "better". There is no point re-writing the manpage here - take the time to understand what an init.d script should do by reading the docs.

I think you want something like:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 99 1
```

You can double check by doing `/etc/rc2.d/*myscript*` to see the S and K levels that it has been set to.